# How do I present text and button elements in a td element without them wrapping?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a table listing approximately 100 products (I believe a table is what I require for the information to be displayed).  At the end of each row of the table is a 'Quantity' input field followed by an 'Add To Cart' input button as shown in the following image:

[image]

The problem that I'm having is reducing the white space at the end of the table.  I would like this column to collapse down to the width of the content without wrapping the quantity and button inputs.

The simplified html is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Picture</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</td>
        <td id="add-to-cart">
            <input id="qty-input" type="text" value="1" />
            <input id="add-to-cart-button" type="button" value="Add To Cart"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And simplified css is:

```
table {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#qty-input {
    color: #444;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 43px;
    padding: 0 12px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
}

#add-to-cart-button {
    background-color: #4ab2f1;
    border: medium none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 43px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
}
```

Note, that I added "float: left" to both of the input elements, otherwise I had a gap between the input elements as such:

[image]

To try to remove the gap to the right I added the following css (as mentioned in another answer):

```
#add-to-cart {
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This removes the white space but gives me another problem in that the floated fields are now wrapping:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0f6LLu0a/

Comment: Remove both your `float:left`s and keep the `white-space:nowrap`. https://jsfiddle.net/cu8bapy6/   (You can eliminate the gap between the input and button by removing the whitespace between those elements in the HTML rather than by using `float`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `white-space: nowrap` on `#add-to-cart` and remove floats. Also you can use `width: 100%` on second `td`.

```css
table {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#qty-input {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#add-to-cart-button {
  background-color: #4ab2f1;
  border: medium none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100%;
}
#add-to-cart {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Picture</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</td>
    <td id="add-to-cart">
      <input id="qty-input" type="text" value="1" />
      <input id="add-to-cart-button" type="button" value="Add To Cart" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked great.  I never thought to increase the with of the other element.  Thank you.  Only slight problem is that it re-introduced the small gap between the textbox and the button inputs.  I just wondered if you had any suggestions on how to remove these?

Comment: One option is to remove white-space in html like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1145/

Comment: Again, that's brilliant.  Thank you very much for your help.